# Python PIL - pixel rgb color to hex

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am looking examples&questions from here. I created things. I want rgb to hex on pixel. My codes but I didn't solve,

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Image

def read(ch):
    return list(ch.getdata())

def hex2rgb(v):
    v = v.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(v)
    return tuple(int(v[i:i+lv/3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv/3))

def rgb2hex(rgb):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

imj = Image.open('sample.png','r')
x,y = imj.size
pix = list(imj.getdata())

if imj.mode in ('RGBA','LA') or (imj.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in imj.info):   
    red,green,blue,alfa = imj.convert('RGBA').split()
    #rgb = imj.convert('RGBA').split()[:-1]

    r,g,b,a = read(red),read(green),read(blue),read(alfa)

for r_,g_,b_ in r,g,b:
    print rgb2hex((r_,g_,b_))
```

Error is here **for r_,g_,b_ in r,g,b:** but How I can solve don't know?

Thank you for interest?
Good works..

Comment: Could you please post a traceback of the error?

Comment: **ValueError:** too many values to unpack

Comment: Please post a complete traceback. Edit your post and put it in there so that one can actually read it :)

Comment: Try to change `for r_, g_, b_ in r, g, b` to `for r_, g_, b_ in (r, g, b)`. :)

Comment: Hi Paulo, doesn't work, the same is error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem:

```
for r_,g_,b_ in r,g,b:
```

The fix:

```
for r_, g_, b_ in zip(r, g, b):
```

But to be honest, you're complicating things unnecessarily:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)

img = Image.open('sample.png')

if img.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (img.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in img.info):   
    pixels = list(img.convert('RGBA').getdata())

    for r, g, b, a in pixels: # just ignore the alpha channel
       print rgb2hex(r, g, b)
```

**Update: getting pixel's x and y positions in addition to its hexadecimal color**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)

img = Image.open('sample.png')

if img.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (img.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in img.info):   
    pixels = img.convert('RGBA').load()
    width, height = img.size

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b, a = pixels[x, y]
            print 'x = %s, y = %s, hex = %s' % (x, y, rgb2hex(r, g, b))
```

Comment: Thank you.
How to get pixel on the color?

So, it is 5,3 as.

Comment: @fthmad9 You mean how to get pixel's x and y positions in addition to its hexadecimal color representation? For that you'll be better using `Image.load()` method instead of `Image.getdata()`, I've updated my answer to show you one more example to achieve that. :)

Comment: @PauloFreitas Awesome ! You crushed the problem in just 10 lines of code !